# Jenkins fails to document because of an dependency to a not yet released package

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, build, jenkins

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I have multiple packages indexed. Some of them are even released but not all.
Now a have a indexed package which depends on a indexed but not yet released package and the Jenkins build complains. Is there a way to tell the Jenkins server to checkout the indexed dependency?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/303507/jenkins-fails-to-document-because-of-an-dependency-to-a-not-yet-released-package/) by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on ROS Answers with karma: 847 on 2018-09-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you want to document a repository `bar` which needs packages from repository `foo` which is also being documented but isn't released you can explicitly declare that dependency in the distribution file:

```
bar:
  doc:
    depends:
    - foo
    type: ...
    url: ...
    version: ...
foo:
  doc:
    type: ...
    url: ...
    version: ...
```

See the following real world example: https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/3c429ecf241ce5c8f447436baf00cb4cac5295c8/kinetic/distribution.yaml#L6234-L6240

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-09-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Markus Bader](https://answers.ros.org/users/390/markus-bader/) on 2018-11-19**:
Thanks it worked :-)